# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList] with root cause

Tags: angularjs, json, spring-mvc, arraylist

I am using RestController in spring mvc4, but I'm getting an exception while sending response. Here I am trying to return `ResponseEntity<List<User>>` of `List<user>`.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList
```

I have these dependencies:

- com.fasterxml.jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar
- com.fasterxml.jackson-jaxrs-base-2.5.3.jar
- com.fasterxml.jackson-core-2.5.3.jar
- com.fasterxml.jackson-dataformat-2.5.3.jar

Comment: Can you show method annotations and signature?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> listAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
        System.out.println("users.size(): "+users.size());
        if(users.isEmpty()){
            return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

Comment: Any particular reason you are working directly with `ResponseEntity`? I would advise adding a `@ResponseBody` annotation to the function and returning simply `List<User>` (and if needed, adding the `produces` option) - see my

Answer (score 1):

Add this dependency in you POM.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
<version>2.8.1</version>
```

The problem is with version of this jar, version 2.8.8 will also work. You need to include this dependency to override the already downloaded jar

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is some particular reason to use ResponseEntity, I would suggest changing the code to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<User> listAllUsers() {
    List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
    System.out.println("users.size(): "+users.size());
    if(users.isEmpty()){
        return new ArrayList<User>;//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
    }
    return users;
}
```

It seems jackson is having trouble converting your List - probably since it doesn't find a proper convertor to JSON of the List (there are some caveats with lists of objects to JSON).

Examples:

[Spring MVC - How to return simple String as JSON in Rest Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895286/spring-mvc-how-to-return-simple-string-as-json-in-rest-controller)
http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/05/json-response-with-responsebody_31.html

Comment: I have used that but no use its giving another error org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver logException
WARNING: Handler execution resulted in exception: Could not find acceptable representation