# How To Fix SyntaxError: Unexpected token b in JSON at position 0

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc, angular-httpclient

I want to read an e-mail address as a string from my backend using Spring MVC. However, when I try to read it using Angular's `HttpClient`, I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token b in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse
```

This is a screenshot of the error displayed within the console:

[image: Screenshot of console]

This is the code I'm using in Angular to read the response:

```ts
public findEmail(username: string): Observable<string> {
  let params = new HttpParams();
  params = params.append('username', username);
  return this.httpClient.get<string>(this.baseUrl + '/findEmail', {params});
}
```

And this is the code of the Spring controller that provides the response:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/findEmail", params = { "username" })
public String findEmail(@RequestParam String username) {
    return utilisateursService.findEmail(username);
}
```

Comment: show your json response

Comment: can you put the `console.log()` of the result to `findEmail()` function call? It could be that your JSON string is bad and is not serialized corrrectly.

Comment: Can you put the smaple JSON

Comment: Usually people at least inline the pictures instead of pointing to some external service. But really, just read the help when asking a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a JSON response, your response is plaintext (an e-mail address) as can be seen by the error in the first screenshot.

Spring by default uses the [`StringHttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/StringHttpMessageConverter.html) when you return a string, which means that it will simply return the string and use `text/plain`, for example `foo@example.com`.

This means that the response won't be valid JSON. To turn it into a valid JSON, you would need to have additional quotes, for example `"foo@example.com"`.

The solution is to:

1. Either return a JSON response from your backend. This can be done by wrapping the response (the e-mail) within a class. As soon as you return objects, Jackson will serialize them as JSON. For example:

   ```java
   @GetMapping
   public User getUser() {
       // Response will be { "email": "foo@example.com" }
       return new User("foo@example.com");
   }
   ```
2. Or to tell `HttpClient` to interprete the response as plain text by using the `responseType` option. This is also mentioned by [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data):

   ```ts
   this.httpClient.get<string>('http://example.org', {responseType: 'text'});
   ```
3. Or to remove `StringHttpMessageConverter` from the existing converters. This will cause the conversion to fallback on Jackson, which will convert the response into a valid JSON string. The solution to do this can be seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37906098/1915448).
4. Alternatively, you could just add additional quotes to your response. For example by returning `"\"foo@example.com\""` within your Spring controller.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are not getting correct JSON Object.Check once api response anf validate that correct JSON is coming from api