# What is the best way to return primitive types/wrappers in Spring Controller?

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, spring-boot

When I return Integer or other wrapper from my Spring Controller like that:

```
@GetMapping(path = "test1")
public Integer test1() {
    return 1;
}
```

The response to the user has the following body:

```
1
```

It's not a valid JSON. Are there any practices on how such values should be returned? The concern is that I want my all API to return a valid JSON. I created a wrapper that returns:

```
{
    "value": 1
}
```

But, maybe there is a better way to tackle these cases?

Comment: `1` is valid JSON. It is just a number.

Comment: @Michael, yes, jsonlint.com also says that it is valid. However, if we return String. Then, even jsonlint.com says it's invalid...

Comment: @Jens yes, I already have one, I'm thinking if it's already somewhere there since it seems like this should be in very big demand.

Comment: @dvelopp A string is also valid JSON.

Comment: Yes, but spring returns it without quotes: Test (instead of "Test")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the return value is returned as plain text, e.g. a `String` is returned without double-quotes, then the following would be true:

- You use `@RestController` or `@ResponseBody`
- Your code doesn't specify a response content type
- The client prefers text response over JSON response

To force the response to JSON, you need to tell Spring by specifying:

```
@GetMapping(path = "test1", produces = "application/json")
```

or

```
@GetMapping(path = "test1", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

---

Since your response is just a number, you could decide that it is just that, and not JSON, by specifying e.g. `text/plain` as the response content type. As with any other response, it is up to the client to correctly interpret the response value.

However, the plain 1-byte response `1` *is* valid JSON, so you can keep that, or you can do the `{ "value": 1 }` JSON response if you want. It is your API, so you get to decide what the response format is.

Just remember to document it, so whoever writes client code will know what to expect.

Comment: What's about String? If I tell spring to produce JSON it returns the following in the body: can't parse JSON.  Raw result:

Test

Comment: @dvelopp You're right, seems Spring prefers the String mapper over the Jackson mapper, so you get unquoted string value. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37819589/5221149) for solution.