# How to merge List to Json java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, java-stream

I have some DB data:

```
//  sequence       subject       unit1       unit2        unit3
//    '2'          'math1',      'root',     'root1',     'asdf'
//    '3'          'math1',      'root',     'root1',     '2fa'
//    '4'          'math1',      'root',     'root2',     '23fasdf'
//    '5'          'math1',      'cosin',    'tan1',      ''
//    '6'          'math1',      'cosin',    'tan1',      'a'
//    '7'          'math2',      'sigma',    'alt',       '22'
//    '8'          'math2',      'sigma',    'alt',       '2fa'
//    '9'          'math2',      'sigma',    'alt',       ''
//    '10          'math2',      'ak1',      'test',      'aaaf3'
//    '11          'math2',      'ak2',      'test2',     'af3vv'
```

And I call the Spring Data JPA using `findall()` like this:

```
List<Entity> call = findall()
```

How to I make a response like this:

```
[{
    math1: [{
        unit1: [{
            root: [{
                root1: ["asdf", "2fa"]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I tried:

```
 Map<String, List<Entity>> listUp_subject = collect.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entity::getSubject));
```

... and ...

```
 Map<String, Set<Entity>> collect2 = collect.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entity::getSubject, Collectors.mapping(Entity::new, Collectors.toSet())));
```

But I can't make like that using Java Stream or by another way. How to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Collecting `List<String>` to `Map<...>` using Java Stream API**

The provided JSON output structure is not compatible with `Map<String, List<Entity>>` but with multiple dictionaries nested as values. As far as I see, there are 3 levels: `subject`, `unit1` and `unit2`. The final non-dictionary value is a `List<String>` of `unit3`.

Therefore, the desired output is `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>>` and chained [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) should be suitable for it:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>> map = call.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Entity::getSubject,                                    // Map<String, List<Entity>> by Subject
        Collectors.groupingBy(Entity::getUnit1,                                  // Map<String, Map<String, List<Entity>>> by subject, then unit1
            Collectors.groupingBy(Entity::getUnit2,                              // Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<Entity>>>> by subject, then unit1 and then unit2
                Collectors.mapping(Entity::getUnit3, Collectors.toList())))));   // Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>> by subject, then unit1, then unit2 and then values are mapped as List<String> of unit3
```

Notice the last line with [`Collectors.mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-), this one maps the structure `List<Entity` to `List<String`. All the mappers used are available as of Java 8 (with the [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) API itself).

**2. Converting output to JSON**

First of all, note that your required sample output is invalid since it mixes the names of the fields with values.

I suppose you return the response through a REST endpoint. I recommend [Spring IO: Building a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) to start reading about the the conversion in Spring from an object to JSON (emphasizes and edited object name by myself):

> The XXX object must be converted to JSON. Thanks to Spring’s HTTP message converter support, you need not do this conversion manually. Because Jackson 2 is on the classpath, Spring’s `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is automatically chosen to convert the XXX instance to JSON.

... otherwise you can use Jackson or GSON or any other alternative "manually". This is out of the scope of this question and have been already asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839753/returning-json-object-as-response-in-spring-boot) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895286/spring-mvc-how-to-return-simple-string-as-json-in-rest-controller). The output in JSON of the code above for your sample input is:

```
{
   "math1":{
      "root":{
         "root1": ["asdf", "2fa"],
         "root2": ["23fasdf"]
      },
      "cosin":{
         "tan1": ["","a"]
      }
   },
   "math2":{
      "sigma":{
         "alt": ["22", "2fa", ""]
      },
      "ak1":{
         "test": ["aaaf3"]
      },
      "ak2":{
         "test2": ["af3vv"]
      }
   }
}
```