# Spring return string as json without creating a pojo to serialize

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am proxying a web request using spring. The response from the end server is a json, i want to pass the json as is to client without creating a pojo for serializing/deserializing. Is this possible?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sample")
@ResponseBody
Object proxyTesting(){
    String result;
    //after proxy result={"success":true , "data":5}
    return result;
}
```

at the client end i expect it to be as is. i.e `{"success":true , "data":5}`

In reality, the result string is nested, and i don't want to create interim pojo's for them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

The question "Spring MVC - How to return simple String as JSON in Rest Controller
" is similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33352362/12485815

Here is one answer provided:

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/user/addUser", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
     
    if (user != null) {
      logger.info("Inside addIssuer, adding: " + user.toString());
    } else {
      logger.info("Inside addIssuer...");
    }
    users.put(user.getUsername(), user);
    return "{\"success\":1}";
  }
```

Comment: You can use `Map<String, String>`

Answer (score -1):

Bad practice but you want something like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sample", produces = "application/json") 
@ResponseBody 
String proxyTesting(){
String result;
return "{ \"success\":\"true\", \"data\":\""+result+"\"}"; 
}
```