# Handling SQL Custom Type as JSON Response using Hibernate + JPA + Spring Web

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity class with a custom type field among other fields

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "something") 
public class Test {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private <SomethingHere> customTypeObject;

    // Other fields, getters, and setters not shown
}
```

Using that class I am generating a json representation of the data using repository.findAll()

```java
@Controller 
public class TestController {
    @AutoWired
    private TestRepository repo

    @GetMapping("/test")
    private List<Test> test() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }
}
```

The JSON response to the user is intended to display the fields within the custom type in JSON format.
If I label the customTypeObject as a String, the reponse is something like below
`[{id: 1, customTypeObject: "(1,2)"}]`
Whereas I would prefer a response like
`[{id: 1, customTypeObject: { A: 1, B: 2 }}]`

I realize I could do this by creating another entity class for the custom type where I manually type out the fields but I plan on increasing the number of fields in the custom type frequently during the development process so I would prefer if the program would keep track of the fields for me.

Is there any way this could be accomplished?

Comment: Have you tried using fasterxml json annotations?

Comment: Can you provide example data from database? Also `repository.findAll()` does not create the JSON representation

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895286/spring-mvc-how-to-return-simple-string-as-json-in-rest-controller

Answer (score 0):

> If I label the customTypeObject as a String, the reponse is something like below [{id: 1, customTypeObject: "(1,2)"}]

based on your example, I assume you are storing a JSON string. You can create a DTO class and use [mapstruct](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapstruct/mapstruct) to define a mapper from your entity to DTO. You can you [fasterxml](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core) to parse the string to object

```java
// entity class
@Entity
@Table(name = "something") 
public class Test {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String customTypeObject;

    // Other fields, getters, and setters not shown
}

// DTO class
public class TestDTO {

   // same fields as Entity 

   private Map<String,Object> customTypeObject;
   // or private Object customTypeObject;

}

// mapper class
@Mapper
public interface TestMapper {

   TestMapper INSTANCE =  Mappers.getMapper(TestMapper.class);
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

   @Mappings({
       @Mapping(source = "test.customTypeObject", target = "customTypeObject", qualifiedByName = "parseCustomObject")
    })
    TestDTO entityToDto(Test test)
    
    List<TestDTO> entitiesToDto(List<Test> tests) 

    // the return type of this method must be the same as the datatype for the field in the dto class
    @Named("parseCustomObject")
    static Map<String,Object> getCustomObject(String objStr) throws JsonProcessingException {
      Map<String, Object> objectMap = new HashMap<>();
      if (Objects.nonNull(objStr)) {
        objectMap = objectMapper.readValue(objStr, Map.class);
      }
      return objectMap;
    }

}

// controller or service class
@Controller 
public class TestController {
    @AutoWired
    private TestRepository repo

    @GetMapping("/test")
    private List<TestDTO> test() {
        List<Test> t = repo.findAll();
        return TestMapper.INSTANCE.entitiesToDto(t);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use either GSON (`com.google.code.gson`) or JSONObject (`org.json.JSONObject`) to create the JSON body manually this way you can manipulate it as needed here is a link to an article that should be helpful

- https://www.baeldung.com/java-org-json
- https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-vs-gson

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Spring, and Spring uses Jackson ObjectMapper, you could create another class to your `customTypeObject` with the respective getter methods to the fields you want to show (probably best to use Lombok's `@Getter` so you don't need to write getters), if you have a getter method Jackson will automatically create the json for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JPA with Hibernate, I recommend to use [Hibernate Types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) for mapping JSON column into POJO, Map, or even JsonNode.

[Here](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/) is an example explaining how to use it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save a Custom object in the database, then you can create your own Hibernate Convertors

- [Custom Types](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-custom-types)
- [JPA Converter](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters) *FYI, But may be out of scope*

You can also try updating the `toString()` method of your custom object's class.

> From your question, it is unclear where you want the desired representation, is it in a database or in a Field in UI?