# How to make RestController handle json Strings properly

Tags: java, json, spring

As mentioned for example in RFC 7159, strings etc primitive types are valid json messages on their own. But the string has to be encased in double quotes.

So, string:

> test

in json is:

> "test"

If I send a properly quoted POST body

> "test"

to the following code

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("test")
public class TestController{
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> userLogout(@RequestBody final String input) {
        System.out.println(input);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("OK", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

the value of input variable is

> "test"

instead of

> test

which would be the correct value.

Also the output of the request is

> OK

instead of

> "OK"

which would be the correct output.

Any ideas how to force Spring to handle the strings properly?

The request does have the correct header:

> Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

And adding produces="application/json" to the RequestMapping annotation didn't help.

(Just a side note: If you use retrofit or Gson for communication, they do handle strings properly.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple string as JSON return value in spring rest controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581619/simple-string-as-json-return-value-in-spring-rest-controller)

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385361/return-json-for-responseentitystring Also try adjusting the consumption media type

Comment: @Bernhard no, that doesn't help, and in that question there is no solution

Comment: @krzyk yes, half of the question seems to be duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`String` is a special type for Spring MVC.

When trying to produce an argument for a `@RequestBody` annotated parameter, Spring MVC choose from a list of default or custom [`HttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) implementations. Two of these are relevant for your example (ordered this way): [`StringHttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/StringHttpMessageConverter.html) and [`MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html) (or the Gson equivalent).

`StringHttpMessageConverter` supports all media types and will therefore be used to read the raw text from your request, which is `"test"`, and provide that value as an argument.

You can provide your own list of `HttpMessageConverter` objects in the order you want. If you put `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` first, then it would be able to parse your JSON as a `String` and produce the `String` argument value `test`.

If you don't want to go through those hoops, you can also change your parameter to the Jackson type corresponding to a JSON string, `TextNode` and then retrieve its value.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> userLogout(@RequestBody final TextNode input) {
    System.out.println(input.asText());
    return new ResponseEntity<>("OK", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

---

The same applies for the response. The value `"OK"` is a `String` and will be handled with a `StringHttpMessageConverter`. Use a `TextNode` or reorder your `HttpMessageConverter` list.

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(new TextNode("OK"), HttpStatus.OK);
```