# How to get JSON format from a Flux<String> in SpringBoot Controller?

Tags: json, spring-boot, project-reactor, restful-url

I am learning Reactor. I use project-reactor to build a Reactor SpringBoot Demo.I have completed a lot of function and successfully GET/POST in my DEMO.

Now I meet a question, the result return from Controller is not JSON format but a Concatenated String like this: `"reactortestPostTitleReactorProgramming Reactor 3.xtestbypostman"`.(I use POSTMAN to test my DEMO)

What I want is a JSON format like this: `["reactortestPostTitle", "ReactorProgramming Reactor 3.x", "testbypostman"]`

Now I put my code:
My basic data struction `BLOGPOST` defined in Entity package, and using `.getTitle()` method could return blog title of String Type :

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BLOGPOST {
    @Id
    String id;
    String title;
    String author;
    String body;
}
```

Model in View, in this class , I use `@JsonCreator` and it works:

```java
@Value
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@JsonCreator))
public class PostContent {
    @NonNull
    String title;
    @NonNull
    String author;
    @NonNull
    String body;
}
```

Controller Code, where I meet question is:

```java
// Get All titles list of Blogs
@GetMapping(value = "/api/blog/alltitles", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Flux<String> getPostAllTitles() {
    return service.getAllTitlesByFlux();
}
```

Service Class Code, I use JPA `repository.findAll()` method to call data from Mysql:
:

```java
public Flux<String> getAllTitlesByFlux(){
    return Flux.fromIterable(repository.findAll())
               .map(post -> {return post.getTitle();});
}
```

So, how I can get a JSON format String List by `Flux<String> getPostAllTitles()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60357183/2897008). This is what going on in your case. You can use the provided solution there.

---

**Easy solution:** You can simply change the `Flux<String>` to `Flux<Object>`

```
@GetMapping("/api/blog/alltitles")
public Flux<Object> getPostAllTitles() {
    return service.getAllTitlesByFlux();
}
```

---

**Another solution:** If you do not want to go with the above 2 approaches, then, You are looking for `List<String>` and based on your requirement, your return type should be `Mono<List<String>>`.  You can take a look at this [collectList](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#collectList--) method.

```
// Get All titles list of Blogs
@GetMapping(value = "/api/blog/alltitles")
public Mono<List<String>> getPostAllTitles() {
    return service.getAllTitlesByFlux()
                  .take(3)
                  .collectList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your link. Your link help me a lot. And more, I tried Your 2 solution. The first solution doesnot work, maybe flux doesnot support it; The second is not reactor style but works. Finally, my success solution is using `Flux<char[]>`, Spring Boot will not recognize as raw JSON string.    And the links is in here[1].   [1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44317740/there-is-a-clean-way-to-return-string-as-json-in-a-spring-web-api?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You mean `Flux<Object>` does not work? I did test before answering.

Comment: The second one you said, ty. I don't think the first one is an option.